# How to implement a function similar to cellfun?

Tags: matlab, cell-array, function-parameter

My problem is about passing parameters to the other function; I don't know how to divide `varargin` and pass values as parameters.

```
function A = mycellfun(func, varargin)
  A = cell(size(varargin{1}));
  for ii = 1:numel(A)
      A{i} = func(varargin{ ??? })
  end
end

...

S = mycellfun(@plus, {1 [2 3]}, {4 [5 6]})
```

Comment: well, so the way you would do this would be to use...`cellfun`...What functionality are you trying to provide that `cellfun` doesn't?

Comment: @Suever it's just a sample, my code would be something different.

Comment: I get that. But the way you do the thing inside of the `for` loop with the `??` is `cellfun`. It would be way more beneficial for you to tell us what you want your function to *actually* do

Comment: @Suever , you already posted the answer and it solved my problem, but about your question, in my code I may change parameters of next iteration depending on result of `func` in current iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `cellfun` to group corresponding entries in each of the elements in `varargin`

```
inputs = cellfun(@(varargin)varargin, varargin{:}, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

The anonymous function `@(varargin)varargin` accepts a variable number of inputs (`varargin`) as a cell array and then simply returns this cell array. It's actually no different than the function:

```
function v = func(varargin)
    v = varargin;
end
```

So for example:

```
varargin = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
inputs = cellfun(@(varargin)varargin, varargin{:}, 'UniformOutput', false);
%   {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}}
```

And then you can loop through `inputs` and each cell element will contain all inputs for a given iteration. You can then use `{:}` indexing to create a comma separated list and pass this as inputs to `func`.

```
A = cell(size(inputs));

for k = 1:numel(inputs)
    A{k} = func(inputs{k}{:});
end
```

Comment: Is second `varargin` in `@(varargin)varargin` a function?

Comment: @saastn No, it's a cell array of the inputs. I updated with a little more explanation of that